# ActiveMQ configuration: BrokerXMLConfig activemq.xml - relative path file not found

Tags: activemq-classic, tomee-8

I'm configuring an embedded instance of ActiveMQ using a WEB-INF/resources.xml file in my Dynamic Web Project that references an external activemq.xml file. ActiveMQ starts & functions as expected using an absolute path to activemq.xml placed in Tomcat's {$CATALINA_HOME}/conf directory. When activemq.xml is placed into the project's WEB-INF directory, Tomcat fails to find the BrokerXmlConfig file using a relative path.

1. Is it possible to package the activemq.xml file with the project in the WEB-INF directory?
2. If possible, how is Tomcat parsing the path to the file?

working resources.xml

```
  <resources>
    <Resource id="jmsConnectionFactory" type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory">
        connectionMaxIdleTime = 15 Minutes
        connectionMaxWaitTime = 5 seconds
        poolMaxSize = 10
        poolMinSize = 0
        resourceAdapter = MyJmsResourceAdapter
        transactionSupport = xa
    </Resource>
    <Resource id="MyJmsResourceAdapter" type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
        BrokerXmlConfig =  xbean:file:/absolute/path/to/activemq.xml
        ServerUrl       =  tcp://localhost:61616
    </Resource>
  <resources>
```

failing resources.xml

```
  <resources>
    <Resource id="jmsConnectionFactory" type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory">
        connectionMaxIdleTime = 15 Minutes
        connectionMaxWaitTime = 5 seconds
        poolMaxSize = 10
        poolMinSize = 0
        resourceAdapter = MyJmsResourceAdapter
        transactionSupport = xa
    </Resource>
    <Resource id="MyJmsResourceAdapter" type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
        BrokerXmlConfig =  xbean:file:WEB-INF/activemq.xml
        ServerUrl       =  tcp://localhost:61616
    </Resource>
  <resources>
```

Other unsuccessful attempts:

```
BrokerXmlConfig =  xbean:classpath:WEB-INF/activemq.xml

BrokerXmlConfig =  xbean:file:WEB-INF/activemq.xml

BrokerXmlConfig =  xbean:file:activemq.xml

BrokerXmlConfig =  xbean:file:./activemq.xml

BrokerXmlConfig =  xbean:file:../activemq.xml

BrokerXmlConfig =  xbean:file:conf/activemq.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

I never solved the xbean relative path problem. Using the absolute path works

```
BrokerXmlConfig =  xbean:file:/absolute/path/to/activemq.xml
```

Aside from the path problem, I ended up not using a separate activemq.xml file. I just used the connection factory with the Default JMS Resource Adapter.

```
  <resources>
    <Resource id="jmsConnectionFactory" type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory">
        connectionMaxIdleTime = 15 Minutes
        connectionMaxWaitTime = 5 seconds
        poolMaxSize = 10
        poolMinSize = 0
        resourceAdapter = Default JMS Resource Adapter
        transactionSupport = xa
    </Resource>
  <resources>
```